# Documentation for ethers.getContractAt()

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

Can somebody please point me to the documentation (official or otherwise ) that explains the  function `ethers.getContractAt():`

the original context of this is as follows:

```
vrfCoordinator = await ethers.getContractAt('VRFCoordinatorMock', VRFCoordinatorMock.address, signer)
```

and the full code can be found here...
https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/all-on-chain-generated-nft/blob/main/deploy/02_Deploy_RandomSVG.js

In the absence of such documentation, an explanation would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `getContractAt()` function is part of the `hardhat-ethers` plugin for Hardhat, expanding the `ethers` object.

It's not a part of the core Ethers package, so it's not included in their documentation.

Hardhat docs mentioning the plugin: https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html#helpers

Comment: will hit this issue after added this line `Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\nick_\VSCodeProjects\xxx\nft\node_modules\undici\lib\api'`.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, it is doing the same thing, that `attach` do but in one line. i.e you can actually interact with an already deployed contract.

For reference below is the code if you are using `attach`

```
let xyzContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Name of the contract");
let xyzContractInstance = xyzContract.attach('Address of the contract');
```

You can accomplish the same thing  in one line via `getContractAt()` when using hardhat

```
let xyzContractInstance = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
        "Contract Name",
        deployed contract address
    );
```

Comment: should be 

await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
        "Contract Name",
        deployed contract address
    );