# How to get signer for a contract?

Tags: typescript, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, ether

I have a contract A that deploys another contract (B).

```
  const A = await deployer.loadArtifact("A");
  const a = await deployer.deploy(A) as A;
```

I can get address of contract B via function and create a reference to contract b:

```
      let bAddress = await a.getBAddres();
      let b = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("contracts/B.sol:B", bAddress, ???);
```

If I will call a function from contract b - I will receive an error: `sending a transaction requires a signer`
So I need a signer to properly call functions from contract B.
What exactly should I pass `getContractAt`?

I tried to pass

1. the deployer, which is (`const deployer = new Deployer(hre, wallet);`)
2. owner from `const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();`
3. tried to get signer from address: `let signer = await hre.ethers.getSigner(bAddress);`

Answer (score 1):

`getContractAt()` is a function of the [Hardhat Ethers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers#helpers) plugin - not of the core `ethers` library. More context in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258500/1693192).

It accepts instance of `ethers.Signer` as the 3rd param.

Assuming you're using a JSON RPC provider, you can retrieve the signer object using `await provider.getSigner()`.

Ethers docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-getSigner